# what must I do to make a AJAX popup window for logging in and out using freemember?

Tags: ajax, freemember

I am looking for an answer how must I code a link to a AJAX popup window for users to login.
I have my login link in a menu that is on all my pages.
Also logout.
I tried to read about this AJAX but I get **very** confused.

Thanks a lot! for helping me out with a simple answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a div. Throw your login box inside.
Style and position it how you want.
Set it to 'display: none'.

Create an event listener, which when triggered, sets the display property to block or anything but none.

Create a listener, which will set it to display none.

```
$( '.context' ).on( 'click', '.my_hidden_Div', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $( this ).show();
 } );

$( '.context' ).on( 'click', '.my_hidden_div .close', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $( this ).hide();
} );
```

Ajax login can be used, but if your having trouble this is a good start.
Simple jQuery.